# Ember.js -- Persist Record on Browser Close

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I’d like to persist a record when the user exits my app. I have the following code in my controller:

```
addUnloadEvent: function () {
  let _this = this;
  Ember.$(window).unload(function() {
    console.log("ATTEMPTING TO PERSIST RECORD");
    let record = _this.get('model');
    console.log("RECORD: "+record);
    record.save();
  });
}.on('init'),
```

The console logs the record when I close the app, but no server request is made. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe because there's no time to fire this request when app closes?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you really shouldn't be saving on `unload`.  Without any more details on the app, it is hard to say the best practice, but maybe have the save action on input change/key-up or even a save button.  The issue with doing it on `unload` is that you won't be able to catch any errors.  I would recommend adding an action to your route to save your model.

```
actions: {
  saveRecord() {
    const record = get(this, 'model');
    record.save().catch(function() {
      // some call to handle errors
      console.log('error');
      record.rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
}
```

Then pass this action down to your template/component (or wherever you are accessing it) and have it bubble up.  It should be easier to debug versus trying to catch errors on unload, which is generally not great practice.

You may be able to troubleshoot the issue better this way. You may find that the issue is on the DB/API side (depending on what is serving your data).  Are you able to save in other areas of your app?

If there is a specific reason why it has to happen on unload would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The reason for persisting onunload is that I want to save the duration of the session if the user suddenly exits the app.

Comment: After talking to some colleagues, we decided that a better way to do this is save the session length to the users local storage, then retrieve it next time they come to the app.